# Collapse a fieldset

Tags: jquery

I have 4 fieldsets in my webpage.I need to have the fieldsets expanded on page load and then collapsed when clicked.The following code works fine when clicked.

I'm new to jQuery.I have few scenarios where I need to collapse 2 fieldsets and expand other fieldsets based on a condition from code behind or using jquery.

How do I expand /collapse a fieldset based on a condition?

I tried using the fieldset id 'Departments' directly ,

```
$('#Departments').parent().toggleClass('collapsed');
```

The above didn't work.

JQuery

```
    function pageLoad() {
        $('fieldset.Collapsible').each(function () {
        var $fieldSet = $(this);
        var $theLegend = $(this).find('> legend');             
        $theLegend.click(function () {                 
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapsed');                 
        });               
     });
```

Stylesheet

```
   fieldset.Collapsible.collapsed {
    height: 8px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    }
   fieldset.Collapsible {
    height: auto; 
   }
```

Comment: Can you please expand on your statement "How do I expand /collapse a fieldset based on a condition?"
What would the condition be?

Comment: 2 fieldsets will be visibleon page load .The other 2  fieldsets will be visible only after form submission.I need to collapse the 2 fieldsets that were visible during form submission

Comment: I know you would love to code it yourself, but try out a UI lib as jQueryUI, Bootstrap or Materialize. Among others, there's a accordion component that does exactly what you need.

Comment: thanks..will try that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use more classes to create groups for which fieldsets will be visible and hidden, and then with jQuery use the toggleClass.

```
<head>
<script>
    function afterCommit() {
        $('.firstVisible').toggleClass('collapsed');
        $('.secondVisible').toggleClass('collapsed');
    }

    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('button').click(afterCommit);
        // Hide the initial second group
        $('.secondVisible').addClass('collapsed');   
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <fieldset class="Collapsible firstVisible">SOME LONG TEXT THAT WILL BE HIDDEN</fieldset>
 <fieldset class="Collapsible firstVisible">SOME LONG TEXT THAT WILL BE HIDDEN</fieldset>
 <fieldset class="Collapsible secondVisible">SOME LONG TEXT THAT WILL BE HIDDEN</fieldset>
 <fieldset class="Collapsible secondVisible">SOME LONG TEXT THAT WILL BE HIDDEN</fieldset>
 <button onclick="afterCommit">COMMIT</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks.will try this.